# Why don't warp cores have shields?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In "Heart of Glory," a Klingon passenger onboard the Enterprise aims his weapon at the warp core in a fit of desperation.

In universe, why not shield it? Any rogue passenger (or a depressed, perhaps homicidal crewman) could destroy the ship very easily in an act of rage or despair.

Comment: The same reason they don't lock the shuttles. They trust people on the ship to be adults, and monitor the crews psychological state.

Comment: In Nemesis, we see that they've installed a '[warp core shield](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/c/ca/Sovereign_Warp_Core.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20100225103133&path-prefix=en)' which they [activate when the ship is going into battle](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/2/21/Sovereign_Engineering.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20080812142559&path-prefix=en). I guess that's not really an answer to the question of **why they didn't have one before that**.

Comment: @Richard We do see Geordi activate a containment field around the warp core, during the show, to help strengthen it.

Comment: @Xantec - Yes, in TNG Disaster, but that's a containment field for the antimatter pods, not the warp core itself.

Comment: @Xantec - And in TNG: Timescape, they wrap it in a "subspace isolation field" but that's purely to stop it from exploding. There's no indication whether that field would prevent someone messing with it.

Comment: @Richard Searching through the Nemesis [transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/movies/movie10.html) for the world "shield" I don't see where Geordi says he is activating a warp core shield. There is a good chance that the images you've linked to are simply of a standard containment field seen in TNG.

Comment: @Xantec - "*Crew members assume battle stations.  Weapons locker ring open and Security Officers hand out sidearms and phaser
rifles. **Geordi and his Engineers establish emergency force field
around the warp core.** Riker and Worf brief officers on tactical plans..."* - [Nemesis Script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Trek-Nemesis.html)

Comment: @Xantec - In the novel it's established that he's adding extra shielding to the core in anticipation of an attack; "*He had stopped and spoken to her, inquired after her assignment, complimented her on her handling of it. He had reminded her of the other officers working as hard as she was: Commanders Riker and Worf in charge of tactical; Commander Data, analyzing every shred of information on the praetor's ship; **Engineer La Forge, adding an extra layer of force fields around the warp core.** And all over the ship, security officers were distributing phasers.*"

Comment: @Richard Those quotes really just reinforce the likelihood of him activating containment force fields as was done in the show: "**emergency force field around the warp core**" and "**extra layer of force fields around the warp core**".

Comment: @Xantec - The ones on the show seem to be designed to prevent an ongoing warp core breach. There's no indication why they aren't up all the time, nor is there any indication that they'd have had any effectiveness against a phaser blast. I just think we've got too little to go on either way.

Comment: @Richard: You wouldn't have energy-based shielding activated 100% of the time if it was only needed 1% of the time. That'd be an unnecessary drain. It's the same reason why they don't fly everywhere with their standard shields up all the time.

Comment: Ha, forget the warp core for a moment.  How could Starfleet miscalculate expected loads so badly that someone could literally *fall through the floor*... in engineering?

Answer (score 5):

**Short Answer**: the warp core is shielded, but not all the time.

**Long Answer**: as Richard and I have discussed in the comments, the warp core is capable of being enclosed in a containment force field. While ostensibly these fields are primarily to protect the crew in the event of a breach so they can evacuate Engineering and eject the core, I suggest that containment fields are also able to absorb the energy of a hand phaser.

In TNG: *The Game* the bridge crew attempt to catch Wesley by blocking off corridors with "security fields". Wesley then sets up a phaser to fire at the field as a misdirection. Despite security fields being meant to control people, including perhaps armed intruders, there is no reason to believe that they are significantly different from a containment field in form or function. And as a containment field should *in theory* be able to absorb the energy of a warp core breach, even if for just a second, there is no reason to believe it couldn't also absorb the lower energy of a phaser.

As for why the containment fields wouldn't always be active, or automatically activate on a red alert, there is no information to my knowledge that addresses this apparent oversight in the Starfleet SOP.

Comment: Easy to invent an explanation, though.  Probably if the force field was left on all the time it would build up a dangerous concentration of <foo> particles or something. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yea, that makes sense as for leaving it on 100% of the time. But they should be able to have it turn on automatically when Red Alert is activated

Comment: Ooh, that one's even easier.  Most Red Alerts are related to stuff happening outside the ship, i.e., a potential combat situation, and when in combat engineering need to be able to access the warp core directly, in case an energy surge damages it or something.  Having to turn off the containment field first might cause a fatal delay.